# What would be the correct way to make a comparison less than and NOT equal to?

Tags: php, comparison, conditional-statements

PHP

Im trying to make a comparison such as:

```
if($card3 < $card4 || $card3 > $card5){
    print "<h2> You lose! </h2>";
}
```

If i'm trying to convey card 3 is less than and not equal to card 4 what would be the correct operator to use?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if($card3 < $card4)
```

is sufficient.  < is strictly less than, so it can't be equal

If you wanted less than or equal, it would be

```
    if($card3 <= $card4)
```

Comment: he's trying to convey card 3 is less than and not equal to card 4

Answer (score 0):

```
if($card3 < $card4 && $card3 != $card4){
.....
```